# MYSQL - cant create view

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT branches.brid, 
COALESCE(a.cnt, 0) AS Assigned,
COALESCE(c.cnt, 0) AS Completed,
COALESCE(p.cnt, 0) AS Pending,
COALESCE(x.cnt, 0) AS Expired
FROM branches WHERE access = 'User'
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT brid, count(*) from task GROUP BY brid) a ON branches.brid = a.brid
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT brid, count(*) from task WHERE stat = 'Completed' GROUP BY brid) c ON branches.brid = c.brid
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT brid, count(*) from task WHERE stat = 'Pending' GROUP BY brid) p ON branches.brid = p.brid
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT brid, count(*) from task WHERE stat = 'Expired' GROUP BY brid) x ON branches.brid = x.brid
ORDER BY branches.brid ASC;
```

I got this error when i create view is there any way to do this? this query works but i can't create view in my data base

ERROR 1349 (HY000): View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: try to put `where` after joins

Comment: how? i dont know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error more or less explains itself.

Here is an excerpt from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html), you need to run MySQL 5.7.7 or newer to be able to use a subquery in a view.

> view definition is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> Before MySQL 5.7.7, the SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery
>   in the FROM clause.
>    ....

You can probably rewrite your query to something like this:

```
SELECT branches.brid, 
COUNT(t.stat) AS Assigned,
SUM(CASE WHEN  t.stat = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed,
SUM(CASE WHEN  t.stat = 'Pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pending,
SUM(CASE WHEN  t.stat = 'Expired' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Expired
FROM branches
LEFT JOIN task t ON branches.brid = t.brid
WHERE access = 'User'
GROUP BY branches.brid
ORDER BY branches.brid ASC;
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN task t ON branches.brid = t.brid
GROUP BY branches.brid
ORDER BY branc' at line 7

Comment: I have corrected that, but you need to be able to correct such things yourself. I do not have your schema, so I probably can't make the 100% correct query that you need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874340/mysql-how-i-can-count-those-rows-from-1-table-using-select-query-and-join/45874638#45874638

Comment: i have screenshot of my schema in that link im newbie in mysql

Comment: Thanks for the help you save my life :>